# "nothing besides the truth" vs "nothing but the truth"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Given that "besides" is sometimes synonymous with "but" meaning "except", is it true that the following sentences have the same meaning?

> "That's nothing **but** the truth."

> "That's nothing **besides** the truth."

Comment: No, ***besides*** isn't idiomatic in your second example. It might help if you think of ***besides*** as equivalent to ***in addition to***, where ***but*** means ***other than***. OR it might be this is just one of those "idiomatically established" usages that you just have to learn.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, That my second example is not idiomatic sounds acceptable, but how might it help if I think of "besides" only as equivalent to "in addition to" while it can also mean "except" or "other than"? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/besides

Comment: Your link to M-W gives TWO d: definitions for **besides** (both written in capitals, for some reason) - 1: OTHER THAN, EXCEPT, 2: TOGETHER WITH. Obviously in many contexts (particularly, after the word **nothing**), "besides", "together with" and "in addition to" are completely interchangeable *semantically*, even if not all three forms are *idiomatic* in any specific context.